# How to see remote desktop setup

Tags: remote

I am trying to setup remote desktop on my Linux Ubuntu 14.04. The first thing I need to do is to enable remote desktop. But I cannot find this setting under System of System Settings.

What do I need to do to be able to see this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Windows button on the keyboard, type remote in the box and you can see Remote Desktop icon (Bash -> Desktop Sharing), where you can give permissions to others to view your desktop.

**Turning Ubuntu Remote Desktop On**

Simply put, turning on Ubuntu’s version of Remote Desktop could not be easier. You don’t need to install a thing: everything you need is built in. Simply click “Settings,” then “Preferences,” then “Remote Desktop.” You’ll be presented with a simple window of options.

[image]

Just check the “Allow other users to view your desktop” button. If you want other users to be able to control your computer, also click the “Allow other users to control your desktop” button.

This window also provides you with a couple of security options. It’s highly recommended that you enable a password, but at the very least you should set it so that anyone connecting to your machine needs your permission before continuing.

As soon as you enable remote connection you’ll be told your IP address on the local network. Write this down.

Ubuntu’s remote desktop technology is based on the existing VNC standard. This means you can connect to a Ubuntu remote desktop using any VNC client. There are more than a few VNC clients around, so if you have a favorite on any platform you can use that to connect to Ubuntu already.

**Connecting From Ubuntu/Linux**

[image]

Ubuntu, and most Linux distributions, comes with an excellent VNC-compatible remote desktop viewer by default: Vinagre. You can find this program by clicking “Applications,” then “Internet,” then “Remote Desktop Viewer.” Open this up and you’ll see all the desktops you can open on your current network. If not, you can always enter the IP you want to connect to directly.

Use this tool to connect to other Ubuntu desktops on your network and you’ll be controlling your computer remotely. Nifty, right? The tool can also be used to control any computer with a VNC client installed.

**Connecting From Windows**

[image]

Want to control your Ubuntu computer from a Windows computer? Don’t worry; it’s more than possible. You’ll just need to install a VNC client, such as TightVNC, on your Windows computer. Then you can connect to your Ubuntu machine just by entering your IP address. Varun wrote all about this in his article about establishing a remote desktop connection to Ubuntu from Windows.

Source: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-remote-desktop-builtin-vnc-compatible-dead-easy/

Comment: Link only answers tend to deprecate and become invalid over time. Please edit your answer with a full explanation.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickNegus Negus for your value suggestion. I will keep in mind